# "return" and stepping through a function in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got some nested `if` statements that perform a certain data check. If the result is what I'm looking for, then I store that data in an array and immediately call `return;` in order to break out of the function.

When stepping through it in the debugger, I have noticed that rather than breaking out of the function immediately, one `return` call instead moves the application to a different `return` call, and *then* breaks out of the function. My question is twofold:

1) Why does this happen?

2) Is it something I should worry about? It hasn't caused me any problems so far.

Here's the exact code below. This happens 100% of the time when the final return in the code (look near the end) is reached. I have put a comment in the code for which `return` the function goes to after that last one.

```
if ([self comparePx:[self getAvgPxClrForRow:rowEdge andCol:colEdge forDirection:0] toBins:bgBins] == nil) {

            colEdge--;
            while (colEdge >= includedAreaOriginCol) {
                if ([self comparePx:[self getAvgPxClrForRow:rowEdge andCol:colEdge forDirection:0] toBins:bgBins] != nil) {
                    colEdge++;
                    prevEdgePt = CGPointMake(colEdge, rowEdge);
                    [edgePtsLeft addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:prevEdgePt]];

                    //FIRST RETURN STEPS BACK TO THIS RETURN
                    return;
                } else {
                    if ([self comparePx:[self getAvgPxClrForRow:rowEdge-1 andCol:colEdge forDirection:0] toBins:bgBins] != nil) {
                        prevEdgePt = CGPointMake(colEdge, rowEdge);
                        [edgePtsLeft addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:prevEdgePt]];
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (rowEdge - prevEdgePt.y == 0) return;

                        isFindingLeftEdge = NO;

                        //FIRST RETURN
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's most likely a result of compiler optimization.

There's a bit of code that needs to run on function before going back to the caller (possibly doing some cleanups or stack manipulations, possibly de-allocations).
The compiler could have selected to not repeat that code, so both "return" statements end up running the same assembly block, and the debugger doesn't have enough information to understand that.

Nothing to worry about.